# Differentiability of trigonometric functions

Tags: calculus, analysis

Assume that the function $f : {\mathbb{R}} \rightarrow {\mathbb{R}}$ satisfies the conditions

$$ \sin(x) \leq f(x)  \leq x$$

for every $x \in [0, \pi/2]$ and $f(-x) = -f(x)$, when $x\in[0, \pi/2]$. Show that $f$ is differentiable at a point $x = 0$ and $f'(0) = 1$.

Any tips on how to proceed with this? The part with $f(-x) = -f(x)$ is confusing me a bit. What does it have to do with the problem? I assume that it has something to do with the range of $\sin$ being $[-1, 1]$?

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Use the fact that, if $x\in\left(0,\frac\pi2\right]\implies\dfrac{\sin x}x\leqslant\dfrac{f(x)}x\leqslant1$.

Answer (score 0):

Since $\frac{f(x)}{x}$ is even, the constraints $\frac{\sin x}{x}\le\frac{f(x)}{x}\le1$ that apply to $x\in(0,\,1)$ apply to all $x\in(-1,\,1)\setminus\{0\}$. We define $f^\prime(0)$ as $\lim_{h\to0}\frac{f(h)}{h}$, which is $1$ by the squeeze theorem.